# specifying path in nunit-console

Tags: nunit

can i specify the path of the dll to run in the nunit-console if so how to do it .

what i do normally is that in command prompt i give nunit-console testassembly1.dll here test assembly1.dll is present in the same path as nunit-console.exe but can i run dll in different path .if so how

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add the path to the commandline:

```
nunit-console.exe c:\path\testassembly1.dll
```

If your path contains spaces, surround the path and filename with quotes:

```
nunit-console.exe "c:\path with spaces\testassembly1.dll"
```